When is upper/lower Dini derivative finite?
Consider a function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Lower right Dini derivative is defined as
$D_+f(x)=\liminf_{t\rightarrow 0+}\cfrac{f(x+th)-f(x)}{h}$
(Also, the Wiki link for the definition here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini_derivative.)
For an arbitrary function $f$, $D_+f(x)$ can take $\pm\infty$. My question is: are there any known necessary conditions for it to be finite? (I am looking for something that is not too strong. Obviously if $f$ is continuously differentiable $D_+f(x)$ would be finite.) For example, if the function $f(x)$ is Lipschitz but not differentiable, is there anything we can say about its $D_+f(x)$? Any tips or reference would be greatly appreciated.
